# How to convert a numeric string starting with 0 to an octal number

Tags: c, atoi, string-conversion

I am trying to do this:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int mode,f;

mode = atoi(argv[2]);

if((f = open("fichero.txt",O_CREAT, mode))==-1){    
    perror("Error");
    exit(1);
}

}
```

However, when I introduce a number like 0664, mode equals 664. How can I keep that leading zero?

Comment: use `strtol(argv[2], NULL, 8);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `atoi` function assumes the string is the decimal representation of a number.  If you want to convert from different bases, use `strtol`.

```
mode = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);
```

The third argument specifies the number base.  If this value is 0, it will treat the string as hexadecimal if it starts with `0x`, octal if it starts with `0`, and decimal otherwise.

If you expect the string to always be the octal representation, then set the base to 8.

```
mode = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 8);
```

Comment: And the third argument is particularly important here, because the conventional representation for numeric modes is octal, whether there is a leading zero or not.  Converting a numeric mode string as if it were expressed in decimal is likely to produce an unintended result.

Comment: Both mode=strtol(argv[2], NULL, 8) and mode=strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0) are making the number go decimal so if I introduce 0664 they set my mode to 436. How can I fix this?

Comment: @EduardoRamos I just tested this and it works properly.  How are you checking the value?

Comment: Yeah, it does work. The printf() fooled me. Thank you so much!